# Inheritance in Specflow test steps cause Ambiguous Steps

Tags: c#, inheritance, specflow

I've read that using inheritance is not possible when using Specflow, which makes sense most of the time. However, I've run across a situation that seems to require the proper the use of inheritance. Here are my classes:

**Base Class**:

```
public class StepBaseClass
{
    protected readonly ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    public StepBaseClass(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        this.scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }
}
```

**First Inherited Class:**

```
    [Binding]
    public class StudioEnterpriseImportConnectorSteps:StepBaseClass
    {
        public StudioEnterpriseImportConnectorSteps(ScenarioContext scenarioContext) :base(scenarioContext)
        {

        }
        [Given(@"I have a data record that I want to send to the import service")]
        public void GivenIHaveADataRecordThatIWantToSendToTheImportService()
        {
            scenarioContext.Pending();
        }

        [When(@"I send the information to an invalid URL")]
        public void WhenISendTheInformationToAnInvalidURL()
        {
            scenarioContext.Pending();
        }

        [Then(@"an error should be generated")]
        public void ThenAnErrorShouldBeGenerated()
        {
            scenarioContext.Pending();
        }
    }
```

**2nd inherited class:**

```
    [Binding]
    public class SitemapSteps:StepBaseClass
    {
        public SitemapSteps(ScenarioContext scenarioContext):base(scenarioContext)
        {
        }
        [When(@"I visit the URL (.*)")]
        public void WhenIVisitTheSitemapURL(string URL)
        {
            scenarioContext.Add("result", TestUtilities.GetResponseCode(URL));
            scenarioContext.Add("response", TestUtilities.GetResponseBody(URL));
        }

        [Then(@"the response code should be (.*)")]
        public void ThenTheResponseCodeShouldBe(string responseCode)
        {
            HttpStatusCode result = scenarioContext.Get<HttpStatusCode>("result");
            Assert.Equal(responseCode, result.ToString());
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the only thing that I'm inheriting the the `scenarioContext`, which is something that I need to do in order to write multi-threaded tests. So instead of repeating this piece of code for each of my classes, I would like to be able to inherit from a base class. What is the proper method of initializing that variable so that I can use it in each of my derived classes?

Comment: Small note to your wording: you write this code for every binding class, not test. Bindings are global, you don't have to write it again for every feature/scenario.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWillich. You are correct. I have updated my language.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way depends as always on your individual situaion.
I recommend always to not use base classes and use context injection everywhere. The small number of code that is repeated in the constructor is a small price for a good separation and splitting of your bindings and their implementation.

To get more info about this topic, Gaspar Nagy wrote a nice blog article about the pros and cons of step base classes in SpecFlow: 
http://gasparnagy.com/2017/02/specflow-tips-baseclass-or-context-injection/

Answer (score 0):

After initializing my Dependency Injection in the Specflow Test hooks, I would have a class called `ApplicationContext` with a static resolve method which would return me my `ScenarioContext` instance like so:

```
public class ApplicationContext
{
    public static T Resolve<T>() where T: class 
    {
        return container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Then in my steps class, I would resolve the `ScenarioContext` like this:

```
scenarioContext = (ScenarioContext)ApplicationContext.Resolve<IScenarioContext>();
```